# How can I take one screenshot every 10 seconds with Puppetteer?

Tags: javascript, loops, puppeteer, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot every 10 seconds but my code is not working correctly. After 10 minutes my lag server. 
My server is much slower and the script stops.

My code :

```
const puppeteer = require('/root/node_modules/puppeteer');

(async function main() {
    try {

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']})

        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080})

        await page.goto('https://www.website.com')

        const video = await page.$('.html5-video-player')


        // Loop problem

            for ( var i = 1; i <300; i++){

                console.log(i)

                await video.screenshot({path: '/var/www/html/test/screenshot/image-' +i+ '.jpg'});

                    await page.waitFor(10000);

            }

        await browser.close()

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("our error", e);
    }
})();
```

What is solution ?

Thank you

Comment: The trick is to use `\`\`\`` around your code instead of indenting it. Or you can select all of your code and use the `{}` button. You may want to clarify (in the question text) what you exactly experience when you wrote "my lag server".

Comment: Does `console.log(i)` print well? I mean, it prints out every 15 seconds?

Comment: It prints up to around 17. Beyond that the server is too slow

Comment: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4431
Puppeteer has issue regarding stuck on the screenshot.

Comment: Screenshotting repeatedly in a loop works fine for me. Voting to close as missing a [mcve] including the site URL.